# [quantstrat for multi instrument strategy]

Tags: r, quantstrat

how do you implement a strategy with multi instruments.
for ex: a multi symbol rotation strategy base on the instrument with the highest momentum.

apply.strategy does not work for multi instrument strategies. Please advise